# How does Akka decide which Actor gets the Thread?

Tags: akka, actor

Say we have three Akka `Actor`s, `A`, `B` and `C` running on a dispatcher with only one `Thread` and the following happens:

1. `A` receives a message and starts processing it
2. In the meantime a message is sent to `B` and simultaneously a message is sent to `C`. Since there are no `Thread`s available, both `B` and `C` put these messages in their mailbox
3. `A` now finishes processing its message and has no more messages in its mailbox, so releases the `Thread` back into the pool
4. `B` or `C` now both need this `Thread`. Are there any guarantees for which will be put on the Thread first?

> - How does Akka make this decision? Does it round robin on all `Actor`s in the `ActorSystem`?
> - Is this decision configurable?
>
>   - Can I say prioritise `Actor` `C` to get Threads before `Actor` `B` in these situations?

Comment: AFAIK an Akka Actor doesn't consume a Thread in "waiting to process a message" state. The Thread should be picked up by Actor when it will receive a Message (of course throughput and throughputDeadlineTime also may matter). So, received a Message - picked up a Thread. AFAIK this decision is not configurable.

Comment: Edited the question to clarify. Two Actors waiting to *receive* a message. Both need a thread, but there is only one available. Which one will pick up the thread? Assume dispatcher.throughput is configured to be 1 and dispatcher.throughput-deadline-time is configured to be 0 ms.

Comment: If both mailboxes are empty - the tread will be picked up by an Actor (given to it by the Dispatcher) who will receive a message first.

If both mailboxes are non-empty - the tread will be picked up by Actors (given to them by the Dispatcher) based on throughput and throughput-deadline-time - in your example each Actor should process  one message and after that the Thread should be passed to another Actor (if another Actor has messages to process).

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't answer my question. If two `Actor`s require a `Thread` as they have a message in their mailbox, but there is only one `Thread` available, then Akka must decide which `Actor` will get that `Thread` first. My question is what is the basis for this decision?

Comment: :) If both Actors have a message in their mailbox, then a Thread already should be busy - picked up by one of them for message processing (who will receive a message first will pick up a Thread first). And after that the Actors should process exactly 1 message per Thread acquisition (based on throughput=1).

Comment: I have put a scenario in the question. In that scenario are there any guarantees if Actor `B` or `C` will be put on the Thread first?

Comment: AFAIK, it's up to message arrival time and task execution order of  ExecutorService that your particular Dispatcher use under the hood (in general - undefined).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole reason why to use Akka is to not have to deal with this sort of thing. You do not want (or need) to prioritize actors in a way like this. Internal dispatcher logic is complex and very well optimized to process tasks as fast possible. Prioritization should be done through other means - like routers, or priority mailboxes.

Now to answer your question: the default dispatcher is backed by a blocking queue - the actor who first received the message in his mailbox will be selected first.